# Rails and Mongoid: Attempting to query database from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

In my controller, I'm trying to get all requests that are associated with each key, which are associated with some user.

```
class PendingsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /pendings
  # GET /pendings.json
  def index
    @pending_requests = current_user.keys.reduce do |key|
      key.requests.where(ready: false).to_a
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pending_requests }
    end
  end
```

However, at @pending_requests, "there is an undefined method 'requests' for []:Array"

There are multiple keys associated with some user, and multiple requests associated with some key.

In the debugger, the key.requests is recognized as a Mongoid relation, but still fails.

Why is this?

Comment: You might get better answers if you include your Model code as well. (minimum working example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're misunderstanding the `reduce` usage.
Try:

```
@pending_requests = current_user.keys.each_with_object([]) do |key, array|
  array.concat key.requests.where(ready: false).to_a
end
```